# Inline expressions <%= %> in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

(I'm sure this question does not just apply to Backbone.js, but I wasn't sure what other categories to include)

In the following video on Backbone.js -
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BDGBJUtAmo
At the 20:30 mark, the programmer uses the following code with inline expressions -

```
<script type="text/template" id="tweet-template">
   <span class="author"><%= author %>:</span>
   <span class="status-update"><%= status %></span>
</script>
```

It was my understanding that the inline expression tags -

```
<%=  %>
```

are to be used with VB.NET and C# code, such as -

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

But the programmer is *not* creating a .NET application. Can someone tell me why he uses those inline expression tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's underscore.js templating system. Well documented [here](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Comment: This syntax is often used in Templating-Engines (see also ERB)